# dataTable - get the new object instead of the old object - RowEditEvent, primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, primefaces

public void onEditRow(RowEditEvent event) {

```
    // old object (Cast) event.getObject();
    How to get the values for the new object?
```